# Unable to save entity in database when field mapping a foreign key is null

Tags: html, spring, forms, hibernate, entity

In my current spring project, when I try insert in the database an entity which have as atribute a foreign key mapping, like that one:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="pagina")
public class Pagina {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "nome", length=32, nullable=false, unique=true)
    @Order(value=1)
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "titulo", length=32, nullable=false)
    @Order(value=2)
    private String titulo;

    @Column(name = "descricao", length=65535)
    @Order(value=4)
    private String descricao;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="parent")
    @Order(value=5)
    private Parent parent;
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
Grave: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp_dispatcher] in context with path [/loja] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.spring.loja.model.pagina.persistence.model.Pagina.nome; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.spring.loja.model.pagina.persistence.model.Pagina.nome] with root cause
org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.spring.loja.model.pagina.persistence.model.Pagina.nome
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.AbstractEntityInsertAction.nullifyTransientReferencesIfNotAlready(AbstractEntityInsertAction.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:801)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:794)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$7.cascade(CascadingActions.java:314)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:432)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:801)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:794)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$7.cascade(CascadingActions.java:314)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:432)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
    at com.spring.loja.config.generic.persistence.Dao.persist(Dao.java:32)
    at com.spring.loja.config.generic.persistence.Dao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ddbbe880.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:711)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
    at com.spring.loja.model.pagina.persistence.PaginaHome$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c9fd6097.persist(<generated>)
    at com.spring.loja.config.generic.service.service.cadastra(service.java:45)
    at com.spring.loja.config.generic.service.service$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c92a3159.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:711)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
    at com.spring.loja.model.pagina.service.PaginaService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a12f460d.cadastra(<generated>)
    at com.spring.loja.config.generic.controller.controller.cadastra(controller.java:42)
    at com.spring.loja.config.generic.controller.controller$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c8cc444b.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:640)
    at com.spring.loja.model.pagina.controller.PaginaController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$34bc66ed_2.cadastra(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Anyone can tell me what I can do to save the data in this case? When the value for `parent` is null, the application should store the record in the database with a blank value for the foreign key, and not try save a empty entity.

**UPDATE**

this entity persistence is handled by this methods:

*controller*

```
@RequestMapping(value="cadastra")
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'cadastra_'+#this.this.name)")
public String cadastra(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("command", this.entityClass.newInstance());
        model.addAttribute("entity", this.getName());
        model.addAttribute("map", serv.getAtributos());
        model.addAttribute("value", serv.getListaAtributos());
        return "private/cadastrar";
}
```

*html form*

```
  <form id="command" class="form" action="/loja/Pagina/cadastra" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3"></div>
              <div class="col-md-6">

              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3">
                  <h3><label for="nome" class="label label-default">nome</label></h3>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <input id="nome" name="nome" class="form-control" type="text" value=""/>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3">
                  <h3><label for="titulo" class="label label-default">titulo</label></h3>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <input id="titulo" name="titulo" class="form-control" type="text" value=""/>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3">
                  <h3><label for="descricao" class="label label-default">descricao</label></h3>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <textarea id="descricao" name="descricao" class="form-control" rows="15"></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3"></div>
              <div class="col-md-6"></div>
              <div class="col-md-3"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3">
                  <h3><label for="parent.pagina.id" class="label label-default">pagina</label></h3>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">

                      <select id="parent.pagina.id" name="parent.pagina.id" class="form-control select" data-lista="/loja/Pagina/listagem2.json"></select>


              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3">
                  <h3><label for="parent.produto.id" class="label label-default">produto</label></h3>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">


                      <select id="parent.produto.id" name="parent.produto.id" class="form-control select" data-lista="/loja/Produto/listagem2.json"></select>

              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">imagem da capa (jpeg, 1280x250)</div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                  <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control">
              </div>
          </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">cadastrar</button>
  </form>
```

*controller*

```
@RequestMapping(value="cadastra", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String cadastra(@ModelAttribute("object") E object, BindingResult result, @RequestParam(value="file", required=false) MultipartFile file, @RequestParam(value="icone", required=false) MultipartFile icone) throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, IOException {
    serv.cadastra(object);
    serv.upload_picture(object, file, "picture");
    serv.upload_picture(object, icone, "icone");
    return "";
}
```

*service class*

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'cadastra_'+#this.this.name)")
@Transactional
public void cadastra(E e) {
    dao.persist(e);
}
```

*Dao class*

```
@Transactional
public void persist(E transientInstance) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(transientInstance);
}
```

Comment: As can be read from stacktrace field 'nome' is null.

Comment: @birya because I don't select a option from the select (value of the atribute == null).

Comment: Can you post the controller class that handles this form submission?  My guess would be that even though you are meaning to insert a single record, your app is trying to insert two, one of which is empty.

Comment: @willOEM methods added. the first one map the view, the second one handle the submission from the form. Short story, I don't insert more of one record, but one record with some blank fields.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through your code I see this:

```
@Column(name = "nome", unique=true, nullable=false, length=32)
@Order(value=1)
private String nome;
```

it means that 'nome' can't be null. If you want it to be null, then remove nullable=false, otherwise make field 'nome' mandatory on your view

Comment: yes, this is not wrong. The field `nome` can't be null, but the field `pagina` can, and that's the problem: right now, I am not able to save a new Pagina in the database because the application isn't accepting save one with the field `pagina` == null.

Comment: then update please your stacktrace, because problem that can be seen from stacktrace is 
org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.spring.loja.model.pagina.persistence.model.Pagina.nome